# How to get post notifications from Facebook page you follow

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I am trying to make a python script that queries post notifications from a page I am following on Facebook using Graph API. However, it seems that Facebook made it more restrictive after the Cambridge Analytica scandal, even if you get it from your own account. What is the legal and working way to either query posts or notifications from a public page?

Comment: You’d have to start by submitting your app for [Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS), if you want to get public posts. Notifications however are none of your business to begin with, if you don’t have admin access to the page.

Comment: @04FS, thanks for the advice. I am not really familiar with the process but I guess it should be straightforward. Is it also possible to do that if I am just individual and not doing it for business?

Comment: Should be possible with individual verification, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review#individual-verification

Comment: Thanks @04FS. Please post your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’d have to start by submitting your app for [Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS), if you want to get public posts.

For the verification as an individual developer, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review#individual-verification

---

Notifications however are only accessible, if you have admin access to the page.